# GitHub not reading JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, github

I am having an issue referencing a locally created JSON file into my GitHub repository.

It works just fine when I view the page I created unto my local machine, but when I sync it into my repository, I get an issue that states in the console: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

and also has this: "Status404
Not Found"

Which I am confused because I am directly referencing the JSON file in my javascript code: Here is the json file, named test.JSON:

```
{
    "temples": [
      {
        "name": "Oakland temple",
        "address": ["4770 Lincoln Ave", "Oakland", "CA", "94602"],
        "telephone": "(510)531-3200",
        "email": "N/A",
        "services": 17,
        "history": [
          "23 January 1961: Announced",
          "26 May 1962: Groundbreaking",
          "17 November 1964: Dedicated"
        ],
        "ordinance":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "session":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "closure":"8pm Tuesday - Saturday",
        "summary":"Ordinances for family names must be done in proper sequence—baptism, confirmation, Melchizedek Priesthood ordination (males), initiatory, endowment, and then sealing. Please allow sufficient time to perform all the ordinances you wish to complete during your visit. For additional help and information, please call the temple."
      },
      {
        "name": "Oakland temple",
        "address": ["4770 Lincoln Ave", "Oakland", "CA", "94602"],
        "telephone": "(510)531-3200",
        "email": "N/A",
        "services": 17,
        "history": [
          "23 January 1961: Announced",
          "26 May 1962: Groundbreaking",
          "17 November 1964: Dedicated"
        ],
        "ordinance":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "session":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "closure":"8pm Tuesday - Saturday",
        "summary":"Ordinances for family names must be done in proper sequence—baptism, confirmation, Melchizedek Priesthood ordination (males), initiatory, endowment, and then sealing. Please allow sufficient time to perform all the ordinances you wish to complete during your visit. For additional help and information, please call the temple."
    },
      {
        "name": "Oakland temple",
        "address": ["4770 Lincoln Ave", "Oakland", "CA", "94602"],
        "telephone": "(510)531-3200",
        "email": "N/A",
        "services": 17,
        "history": [
          "23 January 1961: Announced",
          "26 May 1962: Groundbreaking",
          "17 November 1964: Dedicated"
        ],
        "ordinance":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "session":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "closure":"8pm Tuesday - Saturday",
        "summary":"Ordinances for family names must be done in proper sequence—baptism, confirmation, Melchizedek Priesthood ordination (males), initiatory, endowment, and then sealing. Please allow sufficient time to perform all the ordinances you wish to complete during your visit. For additional help and information, please call the temple."
    },
      {
        "name": "Oakland temple",
        "address": ["4770 Lincoln Ave", "Oakland", "CA", "94602"],
        "telephone": "(510)531-3200",
        "email": "N/A",
        "services": 17,
        "history": [
          "23 January 1961: Announced",
          "26 May 1962: Groundbreaking",
          "17 November 1964: Dedicated"
        ],
        "ordinance":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "session":"Tuesday - Saturday, 7am - 8pm",
        "closure":"8pm Tuesday - Saturday",
        "summary":"Ordinances for family names must be done in proper sequence—baptism, confirmation, Melchizedek Priesthood ordination (males), initiatory, endowment, and then sealing. Please allow sufficient time to perform all the ordinances you wish to complete during your visit. For additional help and information, please call the temple."
    }
    ]
  }
```

And here is the JavaScript code that references it:

```
   const requestURL = '../js/test.JSON',
     divWeathertowns = document.querySelector('div.weathertowns');
 
   fetch(requestURL)
   .then(response=>response.json())
   .then(jsonObject=>{
     const temples = jsonObject['temples'];
       let temples1 = [0,1,2,3];
     for ( let i of temples1 ){
 
       let templeinfo = document.createElement('section');
       let front = document.createElement('div');
       front.className = "front card";
       let back = document.createElement('div');
       back.className = "back card";
       let templename = document.createElement('h2');
       let templeAddress = document.createElement('h3');
       let templePhone = document.createElement('p');
       let templeMail = document.createElement('p');
       let templeHistory = document.createElement('p');
       let templeHistory1 = document.createElement('p');
       let templeHistory2 = document.createElement('p');
       let templeHistory3 = document.createElement('p');
       let templerain = document.createElement('p');
       let templeOrdinance = document.createElement('p');
       let templeSummary = document.createElement('p');

       let link = document.createElement("a");
       let linktext = document.createTextNode("Book Appointment");
       link.appendChild(linktext);
       link.title = "Book Appointment";
       link.href = "#"
       link.className = "firstlink";

       templename.textContent = temples[i].name;
       templeAddress.textContent = temples[i].address[0] + ", " + temples[i].address[1] + ", " + temples[i].address[2] + ", " + temples[i].address[3];
       templePhone.textContent = temples[i].telephone;
       templeMail.textContent = temples[i].email;
       templeHistory.textContent = "Notable Events:";
       templeHistory1.textContent = temples[i].history[0];
       templeHistory2.textContent = temples[i].history[1];
       templeHistory3.textContent = temples[i].history[2];
       templerain.textContent = "Services: " + temples[i].services;
       templeOrdinance.textContent = "Ordinance: " + temples[i].ordinance;
       templeSummary.textContent = "Ordinance: " + temples[i].summary;
       front.appendChild(templename);
       back.appendChild(templeAddress);
       back.appendChild(templePhone);
       back.appendChild(templeMail);
       templeSummary.appendChild(templeHistory);
       templeSummary.appendChild(templeHistory1);
       templeSummary.appendChild(templeHistory2);
       templeSummary.appendChild(templeHistory3);
       back.appendChild(templerain);
       back.appendChild(templeOrdinance);
       back.appendChild(link);
       templeinfo.appendChild(front);
       templeinfo.appendChild(back);
       divWeathertowns.appendChild(templeinfo);
       divWeathertowns.appendChild(templeSummary);
       }
     });
   })
```

Both of these are found in the same folder, called js.

The website I am trying to push the information into is the following:
https://jmoita3.github.io/lesson12/temples.html

Comment: It is in there, I just missed it when I copied it. I will update to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I changed the request from "const requestURL = '../js/test.JSON',"

to

"
const requestURL = 'js/test.JSON',
"